# iPhone Google Maps app-like translucent status bar

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How do they have a translucent status bar on the new Google Maps App? From what I have been trying, setting:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];
```

Doesn't do the job.

I would like to set my iPhone app status bar to translucent in a way that the view behind it could change rather than a static image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `wantsFullScreenLayout` property on your UIViewController to yes as well as setting the the status bar to translucent.

See the [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/wantsFullScreenLayout) for full details.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using xCode 4.5, there's a setting in target summary:

[image]